# jQuery doesn't hide content div of the url in $hgroup.attr('data-project')

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

If you click on any of the images project text and image appears however if you click on 'Back To Portfolio' or 'Portfolio' or 'Contact' the project content remains on the left hand side of the website frame rather than disappearing:

http://www.janinejauvel.com/test/

```
    /* Launching a project
     ------------------------------------------------- */

    $('hgroup').click(function() {

        // scroll to top
        $.scrollTo(0, 250);

        $hgroup     = $(this);
        // hide contact 

        if ($('#contact').is(':visible')) {

            $('#contact').stop().slideUp({
                duration: 250, 
                easing: 'easeInOutCubic'
            });
        }

        // show the loading gif in the container
        $('#slideshow-container').html('<div class="loading"><img src="/assets/img/loading.gif" alt="loading"/></div>');

        $('section#work').stop().animate({
            'margin-top' : '+=' +($(window).height() - 55) + 'px'
        }, 700, 'easeInOutCubic', function () {

            // load the project into the slideshow container div
            $('#slideshow-container').load('' + $hgroup.attr('data-project') + ' #content', function() {
                // bind slideshow
                    slideshow.render();
                    $('section#work').css('margin-top', '0px');
            });


        });

        return false;

    });

}, 

this.folioLinkShow  = function() {

    if ($('.slide').length > 1) {


        $('#portfolio-catcher').hover(function() {

            $('nav#show-projects div').slideDown(200);


        }, function () {

            $('nav#show-projects div').slideUp(200);

        });


    } else {

        $('nav#show-projects').unbind();

    }
}, 

this.loadImages     = function() {
```

Comment: where does the code you're showing fit into the logic?

Comment: $('#slideshow-container').load('' + $hgroup.attr('data-project') + ' #content', function() {

Comment: This is loading the content div of the url in $hgroup.attr('data-project').

Comment: I want to know how to hide it when you try to return to the portfolio / contact page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a selector for your buttons').click(function() {
    $('#slideshow-container').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Although if you then click on the same project again the info doesn't appear to show up any more

Comment: You could use `$("#slideshow-container").show()` for that, e.g. in your `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`.

Comment: You can do $('#slideshow-container').html('<div class="loading"><img src="/assets/img/loading.gif" alt="loading"/></div>').show();